# access vm queue accoss the multiple server in mulesoft

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule4, mule-component, mule-esb

my project requirement to access the vm queue access all 4 op-prem Linux server.
we have 4 project and in all four project applications are deployed. Now how can we access are vm queue persistent queue message across all server. Please help me here or provide any documentation.

Comment: Was the answer useful_

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a cluster with all nodes. A [Mule VM Connector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/vm-connector/2.0/) queue is automatically shared across nodes of a cluster. The documentation of the VM Connector mentions this.